# SBT: sbt.InvalidComponent: Could not find required component: 'compiler-interface-src'

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, akka-cluster

i am trying to run a Akka application in a cluster. Actually i have to Linux machines. Both have the same setup with sbt 0.13.13 and scala 2.10.4, the same Java, even the same kernel version.

For testing the application i have a exact copy of the project on both the machines. When i compile on the first machine, everything works fine. But as soon as i try to compile with

```
$ sbt compile
```

on the second machine i get following error messege:

```
sbt.InvalidComponent: Could not find required component 'compiler-interface-src'
    at sbt.ComponentManager.invalid(ComponentManager.scala:57)
    at sbt.ComponentManager.sbt$ComponentManager$$notFound$1(ComponentManager.scala:34)
    at sbt.ComponentManager.sbt$ComponentManager$$createAndCache$1(ComponentManager.scala:37)
    at sbt.ComponentManager$$anonfun$sbt$ComponentManager$$fromGlobal$1$1.apply(ComponentManager.scala:27)
    at sbt.ComponentManager$$anonfun$sbt$ComponentManager$$fromGlobal$1$1.apply(ComponentManager.scala:26)
    at sbt.ComponentManager$$anon$1.call(ComponentManager.scala:50)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:38)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.ComponentManager.lock(ComponentManager.scala:50)
    at sbt.ComponentManager.lockGlobalCache(ComponentManager.scala:49)
    at sbt.ComponentManager.sbt$ComponentManager$$fromGlobal$1(ComponentManager.scala:25)
    at sbt.ComponentManager$$anonfun$files$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ComponentManager.scala:44)
    at sbt.ComponentManager$$anonfun$files$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ComponentManager.scala:44)
    at sbt.ComponentManager.sbt$ComponentManager$$getOrElse$1(ComponentManager.scala:32)
    at sbt.ComponentManager$$anonfun$files$1.apply(ComponentManager.scala:44)
    at sbt.ComponentManager$$anonfun$files$1.apply(ComponentManager.scala:44)
    at sbt.ComponentManager$$anon$1.call(ComponentManager.scala:50)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:38)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.ComponentManager.lock(ComponentManager.scala:50)
    at sbt.ComponentManager.lockLocalCache(ComponentManager.scala:47)
    at sbt.ComponentManager.files(ComponentManager.scala:44)
    at sbt.compiler.ComponentCompiler$$anonfun$compileAndInstall$1.apply(ComponentCompiler.scala:61)
    at sbt.compiler.ComponentCompiler$$anonfun$compileAndInstall$1.apply(ComponentCompiler.scala:58)
    at sbt.IO$.withTemporaryDirectory(IO.scala:285)
    at sbt.compiler.ComponentCompiler.compileAndInstall(ComponentCompiler.scala:58)
    at sbt.compiler.ComponentCompiler$$anonfun$getLocallyCompiled$1.apply$mcV$sp(ComponentCompiler.scala:47)
    at sbt.IfMissing$Define.apply(ComponentManager.scala:77)
    at sbt.ComponentManager.sbt$ComponentManager$$createAndCache$1(ComponentManager.scala:39)
    at sbt.ComponentManager$$anonfun$sbt$ComponentManager$$fromGlobal$1$1.apply(ComponentManager.scala:27)
    at sbt.ComponentManager$$anonfun$sbt$ComponentManager$$fromGlobal$1$1.apply(ComponentManager.scala:26)
    at sbt.ComponentManager$$anon$1.call(ComponentManager.scala:50)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withFileLock(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:38)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.ComponentManager.lock(ComponentManager.scala:50)
    at sbt.ComponentManager.lockGlobalCache(ComponentManager.scala:49)
    at sbt.ComponentManager.sbt$ComponentManager$$fromGlobal$1(ComponentManager.scala:25)
    at sbt.ComponentManager$$anonfun$files$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ComponentManager.scala:44)
    at sbt.ComponentManager$$anonfun$files$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ComponentManager.scala:44)
    at sbt.ComponentManager.sbt$ComponentManager$$getOrElse$1(ComponentManager.scala:32)
    at sbt.ComponentManager$$anonfun$files$1.apply(ComponentManager.scala:44)
    at sbt.ComponentManager$$anonfun$files$1.apply(ComponentManager.scala:44)
    at sbt.ComponentManager$$anon$1.call(ComponentManager.scala:50)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:81)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
    at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withFileLock(Locks.scala:102)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:38)
    at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
    at sbt.ComponentManager.lock(ComponentManager.scala:50)
    at sbt.ComponentManager.lockLocalCache(ComponentManager.scala:47)
    at sbt.ComponentManager.files(ComponentManager.scala:44)
    at sbt.ComponentManager.file(ComponentManager.scala:53)
    at sbt.compiler.ComponentCompiler.getLocallyCompiled(ComponentCompiler.scala:47)
    at sbt.compiler.ComponentCompiler.apply(ComponentCompiler.scala:37)
    at sbt.compiler.ComponentCompiler$$anon$1.apply(ComponentCompiler.scala:25)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.loader(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:112)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.getInterfaceClass(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:117)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:99)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.newCachedCompiler(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:57)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.newCachedCompiler(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:52)
    at sbt.compiler.CompilerCache$$anon$2.apply(CompilerCache.scala:50)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:39)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(AggressiveCompile.scala:98)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:98)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:98)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.sbt$compiler$AggressiveCompile$$timed(AggressiveCompile.scala:159)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.compileScala$1(AggressiveCompile.scala:97)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:142)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:86)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:38)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:36)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.cycle(Incremental.scala:73)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:33)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:32)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:41)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:32)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:26)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile2(AggressiveCompile.scala:150)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile1(AggressiveCompile.scala:70)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:45)
    at sbt.Compiler$.apply(Compiler.scala:70)
    at sbt.Defaults$.sbt$Defaults$$compileTaskImpl(Defaults.scala:736)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:730)
    at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:730)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (compile:compile) sbt.InvalidComponent: Could not find required component 'compiler-interface-src'
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 02.06.2017 15:52:08
```

I tried the only suggestions i found on this thing called internet:

- I removed .ivy2 .m2 .sbt folders

Anyone having a clue what is going wrong there?

Comment: I had the same error with the package that was provided by Fedora (sbt-0.13.1-8.fc24.1.noarch) on Fedora 26 and I replaced it with an official sbt package. This resolved the error in my situation

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option is to update sbt manually. Follow the instructions on the following page for the package type that your distribution uses: http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error.

After deleting these directories it started working again. 
`~/.m2`
`~/.ivy2`

On windows, they're located under `%userprofile%`